# Can't compare functions in f# for event subscription guard

Tags: events, f#, compare, subscribe, reactive

I'm trying to stop an event from subscribing to an event twice with this:

```
let ex = new Event<int>()
let lst = new ResizeArray<obj>()

let subscribe f = 
    if (lst.Contains f) then // <- doesn't work, can't compare functions
        failwith ("subscribed twice!!")
    else
        lst.Add(f)
        let obs = ex.Publish :> System.IObservable<_> 
        obs |> Observable.subscribe f
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. For example

```
let foo x = printfn "%d" x
subscribe foo
subscribe foo
ex.Trigger 42    // Produces 42 42
```

Looks like we can't compare functions in F#.

```
if (foo = foo) then () // won't compile
(foo :>obj) = (foo :> obj) // = false
```

Is there a way to compare functions or is there another way to stop multiple subscriptions on Events/IObservables?

Comment: No, there is no way to compare functions, and that's a feature, not a bug. Why do you want to have such "protection"? What's the bigger problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps, if you want to distinguish your subscribers, you need to express them better than just functions (google "primitive obsession").

Comment: @fyodor I guess I should have been clearer with my intent. I'm just trying to **detect** when I have done something wrong. When I find a double subscription, I'll change the "higher level" code to avoid it.